# how to display wxTreeListCtrl tree dynamically?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am creating a `wxFrame` which has `wxTreeListCtrl` in it. But, for creating tree I have to send request to backed and then construct tree and then display it. But sending and receiving response from backend takes some time. Till then no screen is displayed. what I want to do is, display a wxFrame with blank tree and then call backend functions, load tree. Once actual `tree` is ready I need to display it instead of previous `blank tree`. can I update tree in runtime? How should I achieve this?
e.g. To update `wxStaticText` dynamically, what I do is

```
staticText->SetLabel(newLabel);
```

Is their any similar function to remove/hide `old empty tree` from `BoxSizer` or `wxPanel` and update/replace/override it with new `tree`?

Comment: What exactly is this question about? `wxTreeListCtrl` has a bunch of methods like `AppendItem()`, `InsertItem()` etc that allow adding items to the tree, what's your problem with using them?

Comment: @alohamora, are you using threads to get the data from the back-end?

Comment: @Igor I am not using threads to get the data from back-end. Should I use thread to get data from back-end?

Comment: @alohamora, yes, it is not a GUI thing and it will help with another question about app freeze. Just make sure you start the thread when the frame is created. And then send the event from the thread in order to update the control. You can also display an appropriate cursor to indicate the program is running.

Comment: Yeah, okay. Thank you